# Localization issue - specific x generic

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, cocoa, localization

This is my problem. I have this simplified chinese and spanish translations that I am about to add to my application. When adding these localizations to my app I am presented with a list of locales like

- Simplified Chinese China
- Simplified Chinese Macau
- Simplified Chinese Hong Kong
- Simplified Chinese Singapure
- Traditional Chinese China
- Traditional Chinese Macau
- Traditional Chinese Hong Kong
- Traditional Chinese Singapure

and I have also an option that is just `Chinese`.

The same happens to spanish, a lot of specific spanish options plus just spanish.

How does this work? I mean, is this option `Chinese` a kind of "wild card" that will work for all people speaking chinese, independently if their devices are set for tradidional or simplified in any country speaking chinese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all about the variations of Chinese here: [Varieties of Chinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varieties_of_Chinese). Bottom line is that different variants relate to geography and geopolitics, so be careful and make sure the translation you are getting is one you want.

The situation is similar with Spanish. Plain ("es") is presumed to be European Spanish. See [Spanish Dialects and Varieties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_dialects_and_varieties) for more info.

To your question, "ES" is generic, in the sense that it will be the fallback Spanish language on the device. If you only have a localization for ES, then that localization will be chosen whether you select "Spanish" or "Spanish (Mexico)". From linguistic standpoint, the common meaning for "ES" is European Spanish.

With Chinese, the story is a bit different. There is no generic Chinese to fall back to. If you intend to target mainland China, go for Chinese (Simplified). If you want to target Chinese population outside China, simplest choice is Chinese (Traditional).

Comment: OK, but what I meant is. Is ES european spanish or is ES generic spanish, meant to be seen by anyone that has any kind of spanish on their devices? I think the later is true because spain has a specific es-ES localization.

Comment: It is generic, in the sense that it will be the fallback Spanish language on the device. If you only have a localization for ES, then that localization will be chosen whether you select "Spanish" or "Spanish (Mexico)". From linguistic standpoint, the common meaning for "ES" is European Spanish.

Comment: OK. my problem is the fallback. I don't want to do zillions of spanish and zillions of chinese localizations, I want one chinese and one spanish to fit all people who talk these languages... please add your latest comment to the answer, so I can accept it.